# Artist name and date of painting

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image: seal and signature ink on paper original art]

[image]

What is the artist name and date of the painting? It’s ink on paper 7.5 in x 8 in.

Comment: maybe, “兆元”  any clearer photo?

Comment: not found same one, but very simluar sytle , the artist name is 刘懋善, hope could help